# How to Join two tables with value basis

Tags: sql

table names: t1 and t2

t1

| flag |
| --- |
| Y |
| N |
| NA |

t2

| flag |
| --- |
| N |
| Y |
| NA |

The requirement is to JOIN each other t1 and t2 tables.

I Interviewer not agree this sql query,

-----select *  from t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.flag = t2.flag;----

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't that just a simple join? I'm not sure what should such a result represent, but ... you didn't explain it either.

Sample data in lines #1 - 11, query begins at line #13.

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (flag) as
  3    (select 'Y'  from dual union all
  4     select 'N'  from dual union all
  5     select 'NA' from dual
  6    ),
  7  t2 (flag) as
  8    (select 'Y'  from dual union all
  9     select 'N'  from dual union all
 10     select 'NA' from dual
 11    )
 12  --
 13  select *
 14  from t1 join t2 on t1.flag = t2.flag;

FL FL
-- --
Y  Y
N  N
NA NA

SQL>
```

Besides, no wonder that your query doesn't work, it is *poorly* written. Not because "it doesn't work", but because it looks as if you wrote it in the middle of a dark night, typing blindly & hoping for the best. Well, that's not the way to do this job.

Comment: Hi #Littlefoot, Thanks for corrected what i'm missed. Thaks for your responce

Comment: You're welcome. So, did you get what you wanted?